# PHP the regular expression for these words

Tags: php, html, regex

Hello guys I want to make a regular expression for these words

1. `<a target='_blank' href='http://www.abcd.com/' >闻闻网</a>6月23日电`
2. `<a target='_blank' href='http://www.abcd.com/' >闻闻网</a>6月23日电 (沈沈蔚)`

I have already try this

```
/\<a\s*target='_blank'\s*href='.*\/'\s*\>.*\<\/a\>.*电/
```

but it doesn't work .

Is there any regular expression works fit for these two words ?

Comment: do you want the right part after `电` to also match? Because apart from that [it's working](https://regex101.com/r/YmFwJH/1) as I would expect!

Comment: @Jeff yes I want a regular expression that can fit for the two words

Comment: but which words?

Comment: @Jeff these two words
1----<a target='_blank' href='http://www.abcd.com/' >闻闻网</a>6月23日电
2----<a target='_blank' href='http://www.abcd.com/' >闻闻网</a>6月23日电 (沈沈蔚)

Answer (score 0):

I alredy find the answer that why my regular expression can't not match the words becuz of the words encode is gb2312 and so I tried this one its work for me .

```
/\<a\s*target='_blank'\s*href='.*".iconv('utf-8','gb2312','电')."/si
```